# What difference does the use of past progressive make?

Tags: difference, tense, past-tense

1. It rained at noon.
2. It was raining at noon.
3. I slept at 5 o'clock yesterday.
4. I was sleeping at 5 yesterday.

Actually, I seem to understand progressive quite well. But what is about the correct use of the past?

Comment: there isn't really a difference between them and you could use any of them in all situations :)

Comment: @alice That's not actually the case.

Answer (score 1):

1 and 3 apply to events which happened at those times. They could have been instantaneous events, or events of a short duration. So "it rained at noon" would mean that there was a short rainstorm at noon. (I don't really like the phrase "I slept at 5 o'clock" because sleep isn't a short duration event. I much prefer "I fell asleep at 5 o'clock".)

2 and 4 refer to continuous events over a period of time, where the time mentioned falls within that period.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. So, would it be correct to say: at some specific time I started to talk to somebody or i still was continuing to talk to?
Is it the same idea about: at that moment i went out and i was still going to leave?

Comment: Both "at noon" and "at 5pm" can mean *the beginning of a duration of time* and are commonly used as such (*I eat lunch at noon* and *I ate dinner at 5pm*). This answer does not address the real issue behind the sentences in the original post.

Comment: @pazzo - They can do, yes. But as a native speaker I really take exception to "I slept at 5 o'clock" - it just sounds wrong.

Comment: @gerol2000 - It depends on the context. "I talked to him at 3pm" - means I had a conversation with him at 3pm, no context needed. But if you were giving an excuse as to why you missed the train at 3.02pm, then it would be "I missed the train because I was talking to him at 3pm".

Comment: We often use the simple past with a time to describe events that have a short duration. They don't have to be instantaneous. I think in general the length of the event has to be relatively short compared to the unit of time. If a conversation lasted for only a few minutes, "I talked to him at 3 o'clock" would be an appropriate statement. If it lasted for hours, I doubt you'd use the simple past. But "I talked to him yesterday" would work even if the conversation lasted all day. "I played football last year" could mean one specific occasion, or many games spread out over the year.

Comment: So yeah, "I slept at 5 o'clock" seems like a very unlikely statement, "I took a quick nap at 5 o'clock" would be possible.

Comment: @Jay - thanks, I agree with your wording. Answer revised to reflect it.